# How to run WSO2 API manager over http instead of https

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

What changes should be made to make wso2 run on HTTP protocol? I tried to change the catalina-server.xml file but then when I run the ap-manager.sh command it's automatically replacing my changes.

catalina-server.xml path:
/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

Also, I tried to change default.json

default.json path:
/wso2am-4.1.0/repository/resources/conf/default.json

Comment: Do you want to access Devportal and Publisher over HTTP? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: yes because I don't get the solution to configure wso2 for HTTPS on the server. can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement? Disabling SSL is not recommended as user credentials will be exposed over the network.

Comment: I have installed wso2 on linux server and the terminal is showing it's running successfully but it's not working when I am trying to call it by  devportal/carbon/publisher from browser.
 
https://subdomain:9446/devportal.
https://subdomain:9446/carbon/ and 
https://subdomain:9446/publisher
So what should I do now to run it by https on server. Do i have to do any kind of  configuration change on wso2 for https ?

Comment: When you say "Not working" what do you mean? Do you see errors?

Comment: That was SSL certificate related issue. So it's working now. Thank you